# Are there any tutorials about getting started with Visual Studio 2010 + MVC3 + MS WebApi?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

I wish to learn about using the new MS WebApi. I've noticed on NuGet there are a number of packages.

I'm not sure where to start and which one to use :(

I don't want to install Visual Studio 2012.

Can I use WebApi in a VS2010 MVC application? If so, how?

The [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) just shows screenshots of Visual Studio 2012 :(

Comment: The latest and greatest is a part of MVC 4, which is compatible with .NET 4.0/VS2010, but is still pre-release.

Comment: Books and tutorial questions are no longer good fit for Stack Overflow and often get closed as non-constructive.

Comment: You can use it with VS 2010. Tons of good resources out there. I have a series on it currently 9 parts.

Comment: Actually that's VS2010 in the documentation :-)

Comment: juts look to the official sources http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: Ah! it said MVC4 in those screenies, so I thought it was vs2012. un blush!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to install Visual Studio 2012.
>
> Can I use WebApi in a VS2010 MVC application? If so, how?

Yes you can use Web API dll in VS 2010. Web API is a part of MVC4.

[Here](http://nuget.org/packages/aspnetwebapi) is the nuget packet, if you don't want to install MVC4

> I wish to learn about using the new MS WebApi. I've noticed on NuGet
>   there are a number of packages.

There are a lot of tutorials on the web.
You can start with the [Microsoft official page about web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api):

Also there is a good starting tutorial at the [Pluralsight official site](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspnetwebapi)

Comment: So I -need- to install MVC4 ?

Comment: You don't need, you can also use the Web API using the Nuget Package Manager dialog. Take a look at Nuget packet.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could pull it down separately. Obvious without the IDE enhancements, though.

Comment: I guess it's all about promoting MVC4 and new Microsoft techonologies

Answer (score 1):

There is blog post which combines the links of many great blog posts, videos and samples on ASP.NET Web API:

[Getting Started With ASP.NET Web API - Tutorials, Videos, Samples](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-tutorials-videos-samples)